# How to create a new mount point that points to a folder in the existing file system (CentOS)

Tags: mount

I have CentOS 6.7. This question is about creating a new mount point on an existing partition. Following is my current disk configuration.

```
Filesystem                    Size   Used     Avail Use%   Mounted on

/dev/mapper/vg_i200-lv_root    50G   41G      6.1G  87%     /   

tmpfs                          3.8G     0     3.8G   0%     /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                      477M   67M     385M  15%     /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_i200-lv_home    172G   21G     143G  13%     /home
```

I want to create a new mount point mymount that point to the folder /home/myfolder. I followed the instructions given in this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/655509/create-new-mount-point-backup-from-existing-partition) in superuser. But when I execute this command:

```
mount --bind /home/myfolder/ /mymount/
```

I get the following error:

```
mount: mount point /mymount/ does not exist
```

So, I want to know how can I create a new mount point that points to a folder in an existing filesystem.

Comment: `mkdir /mymount`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mkdir /mymount` with root user before `mount --bind /home/myfolder/ /mymount/`

Comment: That worked. Can you also tell me how do I view the existing mount points?

Comment: `mount` but i think `df` if more user-friendly

Answer (score 3):

A mount point is "just" a directory. So all you need to do is to create a directory with "mkdir /mymount", or use an existing one (but be aware that if you do mount over an existing directory, anything "below" that directory will be hidden -- although that may well be the effect you're trying to achieve).